# Is modifying the key set of a map okay, or is it an abuse of a map in Java with undefined behavior?

Tags: java, dictionary, set

I noticed that we can manipulate the set of keys in a map in Java.

For example, here we copy a map, then effectively remove some of the entries by modifying the set of keys with a call to `Set:retainAll`.

```java
Map< DayOfWeek , String > dailyAssignment = new EnumMap<>( DayOfWeek.class ) ;
dailyAssignment.put( DayOfWeek.MONDAY, "Alice" ) ;
dailyAssignment.put( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, "Bob" ) ;
dailyAssignment.put( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, "Bob" ) ;
dailyAssignment.put( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, "Carol" ) ;

List< DayOfWeek > weekend = List.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;

Map< DayOfWeek , String > weekendAssignment = new EnumMap<>( dailyAssignment ) ;
weekendAssignment.keySet().retainAll( weekend ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "dailyAssignment.toString(): " + dailyAssignment ) ;
System.out.println( "weekendAssignment.toString(): " + weekendAssignment ) ;
```

This seems to work, as seen in Java 12 when [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/bqmW0b).

> dailyAssignment.toString(): {MONDAY=Alice, TUESDAY=Bob, SATURDAY=Bob, SUNDAY=Carol}

> weekendAssignment.toString(): {SATURDAY=Bob, SUNDAY=Carol}

➥ While it seems to work, is this a proper use of a key set in a map? The Javadoc for [`EnumMap::keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html#keySet()) method does not address mutability of the returned key set.

Comment: Dear down-voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Comment: Go for it. If you're ever in doubt about an implementation choice, write lots of unit tests to give you confidence that it works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, mutating the `Set` of keys in a `Map` is a supported feature.

Look the Javadoc of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) rather than its implementation [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html). The [`Map::keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) documentation specifically states that altering the set of keys is an acceptable way to mutate the map.

To quote [`Map::keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) Javadoc: *…The set supports element removal…*

> Returns a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined. The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the `Iterator.remove`, `Set.remove`, `removeAll`, `retainAll`, and `clear` operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.